# When installing app from the Xcode for debug purpose it's run over another app in the device

Tags: iphone, xcode

When i'm installing an app from Xcode for debug purpose on the device it's run over another app  that I developed in the device (that been download from the appStore). 
also it's happen vice versa, any ideas???

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have set the Bundle Identifier (in the Info.plist file) to a value that's specific to you; the convention is to use a reverse-DNS-style identifier of a domain that you own (com.adomainthatyouown.theappname).

Comment: yes i did in both of the apps, the one in the appstore and the one i'm developing now.

Comment: Are they the same as each other?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that it the app you are testing deletes a different app you downloaded from the app store?

Comment: yes it deleting the app that i developed and i downloaded it from the appstore, it also deleting vice versa - when i downloading the app again from the appstore it deleting the app that i'm testing.
both are different apps.